# How to rename reserved app name given for Windows Phone Store app for Beta Test?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have submitted an app for beta testing in Windows phone Store, Unfortunately I used my original app name for it. Now I cannot use the same name for  publishing the app for public. Is there any way to use the same name for publish the app? Does deleting/unpublish will release the reserved app name? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes you have to unpublish or delete the app from the store. Give it a try as there is no any other ways to use the same reserved name.

Comment: Yeah, I just did the same and submitted it for review in public store, Thanks a lot